# IOS duplicate interface definition

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface

hello i have the code below on my .h file

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface NSFont : NSObject <NSCoding> {

}

@end


@interface NSParagraphStyle : NSObject <NSCoding> {

}

@end
```

and i get that error :

> error: duplicate interface definition for class 'NSParagraphStyle'

i have no includes and no duplicates as pointed by some users

main.m imports

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

pref

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Both of these classes are defined in AppKit framework (so it shouldn't be a problem if you're developing for iOS - apart from the fact that `NS` prefixed classes is a really bad idea). Are you sure that you're on an iOS project?

Comment: yes it is and it was working fine on previous xcode

Comment: Is it possible to post the imports of your `main.m` and `prefix.pch` files?

Comment: Naming your classes with the same namespace as Apple is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSParagraphStyle was added in the latest (unreleased) version of iOS. So you don't need to define it yourself. You probably need to change the name, don't use NS as prefix in that case.

Answer (score 4):

`NSParagraphStyle` already exists ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Any why are you using the `NS` namespace - if you want to creat your own classes, make your own namespace and precede your class names with that (i.e. `MHParagraphStyle`) so your paragraphStyle class won't clash with the built in one :)

Comment: That's why I made also a comment about this. The thing is that the class is defined in `AppKit` framework and not in `UIKit` (so technically it should be fine)

Comment: Don't name your classes with the same namespace as Apple. It's a recipe for disaster if Apple happens to port classes to UIKit. Suddenly the app will no longer compile...

Comment: @futureelite7 - that's exactly what's happened here :)